# How can I set bootstrap's @baseFontSize if using a CDN?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I was using v2.0.4 of [Bootstrap via a public CDN](http://www.bootstrapcdn.com/).

Recently (August 20, 2012) version 2.1.0 was released and one of the things among the changes was a [new base font-size and line-height](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/wiki/Changelog), which are in fact just a little bit bigger.

I understand this is set in `variables.less` and so if I'm using a pre-compiled version I may likely be stuck with the settings - but is there any good way to override things and "reset" the base font-size to something a little bit smaller when using this CDN version, and without having to specify a font-size override for each element that I want to affect?

`body{ font-size:.9em; }` unfortunately doesn't help.

2.0.4 rendered H2 font size:

[Picture 2.png http://img819.imageshack.us/img819/7048/picture2ww.png](http://img819.imageshack.us/img819/7048/picture2ww.png)

2.1.0 rendered H2 font size:

[Picture 1.png http://img687.imageshack.us/img687/8741/picture1qvc.png](http://img687.imageshack.us/img687/8741/picture1qvc.png)

Old and new compressed CSS in case anyone wants to fiddle:

```
http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.0.4/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css
```

and newer:

```
http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.1.0/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css
```

Comment: I was going to suggest (as mostly a last resort) compiling your own reduced version of **type.less**, but then I noticed that the `<h*>` tags don't even use the `@baseFontSize` and `@baseLineHeight` in 2.1.1! So, you'd end up having to manually configure them anyway.  I hope someone else has a better idea.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@cwd

Well clearly you didn't RTFM. Try:

`http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.1.1/css/bootstrap-combined-for-cwd.min.css`

=P

[image]

Comment: Where's TFM that explains what you've done here? I want to R it.